# redirect to 404 if user has entered question mark in uri

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

`localhost:8080/TIC/#/login` is the URI which I use to login to my app.

If I use `localhost:8080/TIC/?iuuigiihihio#/login`, my application is logging in but I need to redirect to `404`.

Do I need to avoid the `?` parameter before `#`?

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('#');
```

Comment: Make sure to add what you have tried so far and what went wrong. Also try to include output and/or errors so we can better help you. Remember, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, but there are a lot of helpful people here that are willing to take a look if you make an effort to explain your problem.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

`$location.absUrl()` will give you your full URL, where you can manually search for your characters. For example:

```js
/* $scope.str = $location.absUrl(); */
str = "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo";
i1 = str.match(/\?/).index;
i2 = str.match(/\#/).index;
console.log("? is before # :",i1 < i2);

/* do something if true/false */
```